# Logical operator NOT outside parentheses returning confusing results

Tags: sql, hiveql

I have the following `WHERE` clause:

`NOT (division = 'Freemium' AND team = 999 AND touch IS NULL)`

I expected this to be the same as:

`no WHERE clause`

minus

`(division = 'Freemium' AND team = 999 AND touch IS NULL)`

but it is not. There are some differences when looking at the counts. Any insight?

As an fyi, I am using HiveQL, but don't expect this to be any different for MySQL/SQL.

---

added:

Original Query:

```
CREATE TABLE AS example_so AS
SELECT
  ticket_id,
  division,
  team,
  touch
FROM sample_table
WHERE
  day >= '2016-01-01' AND
  current_state <> 'deleted'
GROUP BY
  ticket_id,
  division,
  team,
  touch;
```

Query A:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT ticket_id)
FROM example_so
```

**Result: 81,336**

Query B:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT ticket_id)
FROM example_so
WHERE
  (team = 999 AND division = 'Freemium' AND touch IS NULL)
```

**Result: 355**

Query C:

```
SELECT
  COUNT(DISTINCT ticket_id)
FROM example_so
WHERE
  NOT (team = 999 AND division = 'Freemium' AND touch IS NULL)
```

**Result: 80,682**

Comment: Does MINUS perhaps remove duplicates? (Like UNION does.)

Comment: No, it shouldn't be that. There shouldn't be any duplicates there and I am using COUNT DISTINCT.

Comment: Count distinct will obviously remove duplicates. It's difficult to say as you've only provided a small part of the query. The problem is probably to do with what you're counting and using distinct but you haven't shown us this part of the query.

Comment: I have added the original queries now for some more context.

Comment: Try this query: `SELECT
  DISTINCT ticket_id, team, division, touch
FROM example_so

minus 

(SELECT
 DISTINCT ticket_id, team, division, touch
FROM example_so
WHERE
  (team = 999 AND division = 'Freemium' AND touch IS NULL)
  )
  
minus

(SELECT
  DISTINCT ticket_id, team, division, touch
FROM example_so
WHERE
  NOT (team = 999 AND division = 'Freemium' AND touch IS NULL)
  )` and try to provide us with results, this will allow us to debug your problem.

Comment: Ok, so I did that, and the results that came back (299 results, as one would expect), all involve the following:

team = NULL,
division = 'Freemium',
touch = NULL so it must be an issue with the team = NULL part. Why though?

Comment: Ok let me write it as an answer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To check for null values in MySQL, you need to use IS NULL.
So for rows with `team is null`, team is not equal to 999, and is not `"not equal"` to 999 neither, because it's null. 
To better understand this, try to run this query:

```
select a from (select null as a)a where  (a<>1)
```

it will return 0 rows.

So the reason why `count(table C) + Count(table B) <> count(table A)` is that both queries B and C don't include teams with `null`, while query A does.

Basically, try to avoid using `where` conditions with logical `NOT` as it can be very confusing, and try to negate your expressions instead.
Like:

```
NOT (division = 'Freemium' AND team = 999 AND touch IS NULL)
```

Should be:

```
(division <> 'Freemium' or division is null 
or team <> 999 or team is null or touch IS NOT NULL)
```